# force:mdapi:convert command fails when source has a utility js file

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package, mdapi

I'm trying to follow the [SFDX Developer Guide to convert an unlocked package to SFDX source format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm)

I'm receiving the following error:

```
$ sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir mdapipkg --outputdir tmp_convert

**ERROR running force:mdapi:convert:  An error was encountered processing path: /Users/*****/SFDX/tempCore/mdapipkg/unpackaged/lwc/****ButtonComponent/***ButtonComponentUtils.js**

Version - sfdx-cli 7.36.0 (core)
```

Comment: Does using the `--dev-debug` flag output anything more useful?

Comment: no..seems like a open issue on cli. https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/31